# Python and Regex - Replace Date

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple strings in the form of :

```
AM-2019-04-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24
```

And I need the month from the date part replaced with something else, for example:

```
AM-2019-07-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24
```

How can I achieve this using python and regex?

Also, I have multiple text files that contain a line similar to this:

```
LocalTime: 21/4/2019 21:48:41
```

And I need to do the same thing as above (replace the month with something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first example:

```
import re
string = 'AM-2019-07-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24'
replace = '0'+str(int((re.match('(AM-\d{4}-)(\d{2})',string).group(2)))+2)

re.sub('(AM-\d{4}-)(\d{2})',r'\g<1>'+replace,string) #Replace 07 for 07 +2
```

Output:

```
Out[10]: 'AM-2019-09-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24'
```

For the second one:

```
string2 = 'LocalTime: 21/4/2019 21:48:41'
replace = str(int((re.match(r'(LocalTime: \d{1,2}/)(\d{1,2}).*',string2).group(2)))+2)
re.sub('(Time: \d{2}/)(\d{1,2})',r'\g<1>'+replace,string2) #Replace 4 for 6
```

Output:

```
Out[14]: 'LocalTime: 21/6/2019 21:48:41'
```

If you want to limit the months in which this operation is done, you can use an `if` statement:

```
 if re.match('(AM-\d{4}-)(\d{2})',string).group(2).isin(['04','05','06']:

 if re.match(r'(LocalTime: \d{1,2}/)(\d{1,2}).*',string2).group(2).isin(['4','5','6']:
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Is it also possible to only replace a certain month? What I am trying to do is replace month 06 with 07, month 07 with 08 and so on.

Comment: So, between January and May you don't replace, and from June you replace with month+1 ? What happens in December?

Comment: The date starts from April and ends in June. I want to replace April with June, May with July, and June with August.

Comment: Check at my edit, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer but with more code and a lookbehind.

First question:

```
import re

#This could be any number of strings, or some other iterable
string_list = []

string_list.append("AM-2019-04-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24")
string_list.append("AM-2019-07-22 06-47-57865BCBFB-9414907A-4450BB24")

#This checks for four digits and a hyphen, then any number of digits to
#replace (which is the month
pattern = r"(?<=\d{4}-)\d+"
#This should be a string
month = "08"
for string in string_list:
    print("BEFORE:  " + string)
    string = re.sub(pattern, month, string)
    print("AFTER:  " + string)
```

Second question:

```
import re

#checks for a colon, 2 numbers, a forward slash, and then selects however many numbers after (which is the month)
pattern = r"/(?<=: \d{2}/)\d+"

#IMO it's better just to write to another file. You can edit the current file you're on, but it's cleaner this way and you won't accidentally screw it up if my regex is wrong.
in_file = open("mytextfile.txt", 'r')
out_file = open("myoutputfile.txt", 'w')
#This should be a string
month = "9"

for line in in_file:
    changed_line = re.sub(pattern, month, line)
    out_file.write(changed_line)

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would be the pattern if I wanted to target only a certain month? For example "07" for the first question and "7" for the second one?

Comment: Replace the ```d+``` with 07 and 7 respectively. d+ just represents looking for a number of any length, so if you want to replace it with only finding 07, it will only find strings where it has 07 immediately after the previous qualifiers.